# keystrokes out of order

Tags: 14.04

I am running a fairly recent Lubuntu and often when there is a task in the background or something else that takes a lot of CPU cycles, I get keystrokes out of order when I type in a window that is in the process of initialization. For example, in the browser (Chrome) when it is still redrawing its UI.

Has anyone seen this?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an ibus problem: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410649

In short, ibus in synchronous mode does funny things.  There is a workaround from the bottom of that link, referring to https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1697#c2 :

```
Also for the record the user can work around the problem by setting
IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1

IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=0 ibus-daemon --xim --replace --verbose    --- This exhibits the problem.
IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1 ibus-daemon --xim --replace --verbose    --- This works fine.
IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=0 ibus-daemon --replace --verbose    --- This works fine.
IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1 ibus-daemon --replace --verbose    --- This works fine.
```