# Why are the characters that I typed missing or out of order?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, xdotool

Sometimes when I use LUbuntu 18.04 to type my questions here, the editor echos what I type very slowly.   I  always believe it is because of memory running out (e.g. too many opened webpages), but this time it looks like CPU instead (I have two cores that are running several background jobs of mine).

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        4.6G        988M        543M        2.1G        2.3G
Swap:           14G        2.0G         12G

$ uptime
 10:58:39 up 6 days, 21:52,  1 user,  load average: 6.96, 7.61, 7.80
```

More importantly, it misses some characters that I type or change their order. For example, when I type "mean", it echos "man", "daemon" becomes "damon", "memory" becomes "meory", and "cron" becomes "corn".
I wonder why character missing and out of order happens instead of just echoing  slowing down? I am wondering if the Linux IO subsystem has anything to do with it, in case of memory or CPU being tight.

I also remember the out or order problem sometimes happens when I use `xdotool`. Some delay between typing characters or some other way may solve the problem (I don't remember the exact solution).

[Another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522605/keystrokes-out-of-order) seems to mention the same problem as mine.
Thanks.

Comment: I could explain missing characters: The system is too busy to listen when you type them. But I don't know the reason why they are out of order (except that your fingers type them out of order).

Comment: Did you try the suggested fix as mentioned in the link?  [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770466/where-to-add-export-ibus-enable-sync-mode-1) has a clue about where to insert the setting